# draw histogram on panel

Tags: c#, sql-server, panel

Could anyone tell me how to draw a histogram on a panel? The data used for the histogram is taken from sql statements. The functions that get the data are

```
 ArrayList getGrupe()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                         "Trusted_Connection=yes;database=erp;connection timeout=30");
            ArrayList listaGrupe = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select distinct(grupa) from [erp].[dbo].Clienti";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                    listaGrupe = new ArrayList();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listaGrupe.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return listaGrupe;
        }

        ArrayList getVanzariGrupa(string grupa)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                 "Trusted_Connection=yes;database=erp;connection timeout=30");
            ArrayList vanzari = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select sum(f.cantitate*lp.pret)+" +
                "(sum(f.cantitate*lp.pret)*24/100) as Vanzari_totale From " + 
                " [erp].[dbo].Facturi_iesire f, [erp].[dbo].Clienti c, " + 
                " [erp].[dbo].Arhiva_comenzi a, [erp].[dbo].Produse p, " + 
                " [erp].[dbo].Lista_preturi lp " + 
                " where f.id_arhiva_comenzi=a.id_arhiva_comenzi and " + 
                " a.cod_produs=p.cod_produs and p.cod_produs=lp.cod_produs and " + 
                "lp.id_lista=c.id_lista and c.grupa='"  +
                 grupa.ToString() + "' Group by c.nume;";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 if (reader.HasRows)
                    vanzari = new ArrayList();
                while (reader.Read())
                 {
                    vanzari.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
             finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
             return vanzari;
        }
```

GetGrupe() will represent the number of bars and getVanzariGrupa() gets the data for each bar, so the height of each bar will depend on the value returned from getVarnzariGrupa() for each grupa so I was thinking that it could be ok to use 2 foreach. Something like this

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        grupe = new ArrayList();
        grupe=getGrupe();
        foreach (string grupa in grupe)
        {
            ArrayList date = getVanzariGrupa(grupa);
            foreach (String vz in date)
            {
                //proccesing the data to draw the histogram ???
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: Have you considered using a Chart control? Also adding a little sketch of what you would like to see would help helping you with the paint code.. (BTW: ArrayList is deprecated; use List<T> or another of the wonderful generic collections instead! You'll love 'em)

Comment: Also: While `foreach` is really easy to use, the good old `for` loop will give you the counter variables you'll need in the paint code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **could** script the Paint event to use a

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gBrush, x, y, w, h);
```

to create a very simple histogram. And you could use a

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(groups[g], someFont, gBrush, panel1.Width - marging, g*20f);
```

to draw a minimal legend. The real work would be in getting the values of margin, x, y, w, h right..

**This is not a good idea**! Painting a histogram is the job of the nice and ready made `Chart` control in the Data controls section of the Toolbox. Place one on the Form instead of the `Panel` and name it, say `groupChart`.

Using it takes as little code as this:

```
private void button_charts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I recommend changing this too, say List<string>
    ArrayList grupe = getGrupe();

    // clear the chart
    groupChart.Series.Clear();

    // loop over the groups..
    for (int g = 0; g < groups.Count; g++)
    {
        // add a series and configure it..
        // I simply set it to be of type column:
        Series ser = groupChart.Series.Add(groups[g]);
        ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        // now get your list of values..
        // you pick the data type!!
        List<int> date = getVanzariGrupa(groups[g]); //*

        for (int v = 0; v < date .Count; v++)
        {
            ser.Points.AddXY(v, date [v]);
        }

    }
}
```

Done. You can configure the `Chart` in many ways, like ticks, labelling etc. Well worth looking at.

For this to work do get rid of at least the `Arrraylist` of 'date'! Change this

```
ArrayList getVanzariGrupa(string grupa)
```

and these:

```
ArrayList vanzari = null;
vanzari = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
List<T> getVanzariGrupa(string grupa)
```

and this:

```
 List<T> vanzari = new List<T>();
 vanzari = new List<T>();
```

For 'T' you simply insert the **data type** you expect from your `sum()` clause; for float  it is: chose `List<float>`. You can see the wonderful flexibility of the generic collections at work!

**Edit:** //* this was wrong in the first version!

Comment: I've made the modifications you said but it doesn't work. It gives me an object not set to an instance of an object error. When I'm in debugger it seems that the error comes from the getVanzariGrupa() function, from the query because instead of getting the value of the list element it puts System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] so the query returns null. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ouch, that what a stupid mistake of mine.. The List must be instantiated. See my edited answer! Also, don't add the values as strings, of course! What data type does come out of the query?

Comment: It still doesn't work. The same error. from getGrupe() I return string and from getVanzariGrupa I get float.

Comment: Yes, the argument was wrong. (Still the one from the foreach loop) See the correction! Does it work now and show a histogram?

Comment: Good. If you feel that it has solved your problem, you may want to consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.